# Getting return value bind to a specific function

Tags: javascript

Stuck with some peculiar problem, help will be appreciated

```
// image Editor
function AddPic() {
    var ret=loadpic();
    console.log("retval=" + ret);
}
```

2nd file imported into 1st

```
var retval;
function loadpic() {
  //loads pictures in canvas frames and allow user to edit
  return function doneOK() {
      return retval;
  };
}
function edit1() { retval=1;}
function edit2() { retval=2;}
function edit3() { retval=3;}
function edit4() { retval=4;}
function edit5() { retval=5;}
function edit6() { retval=6;}
//Depending on the user action different functions are called
//user can take any amount of time before clicking "OK" 
function onlclickOK() {doneOK();}

<html>
    <input type=button onclick=onlclickOK() value="ok">
</html>
```

issue:
when user clicks on the ok button
we need to call the doneok() function 
which further return the retval value to the calling page

this is where i am struck;

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: How do you bind the `onlclickOK` function to the actual click event?

Comment: dear joe "issues:updated"

Comment: onlclickOK will be fired by a user action, when user clicks on the ok Button

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but could you provide the code for it?

Comment: updated in the code

Comment: How and where exactly are: `AddPic()`,  `Edit()..` are getting called? Can you provide the complete code?

Comment: What are `edit1`, `edit2` etc functions? I think you have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Still there are some better ways to do. In case, this may help a little bit in calling the function to get the retval.


function loadpic() {
  //loads pictures in canvas frames and allow user to edit
  return doneOK()
}



function doneOK() {
  return retval;
};
```

Comment: There is some user interaction before doneok() need to be called

and to be triggered by some user action (click on ok button)

Comment: So your requirement is, you are loading the pictures in the canvas frames with Edit button on each image. Once user click that edit button on specific image, then retval of that image should be fetched inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect the return value to be available *now*, when the user will only click the button in the *future*. So you need an asynchronous solution. Nowadays you would use Promises for that, and `async` `await` keywords.

You would also need to start listening to the OK button click when `loadPic` is called, not before.

Here is how that could look:

```
async function AddPic() {
    var ret = await loadpic();
    console.log("retval=" + ret);
}
```

2nd file imported into 1st would become:

```
var onlclickOK = () => null; // null operation
var retval;
function loadpic() {
    //loads pictures in canvas frames and allow user to edit
    // ...
    // ...
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        onlclickOK = () => resolve(retval);
    });
}
function edit1() { retval=1;}
function edit2() { retval=2;}
function edit3() { retval=3;}
function edit4() { retval=4;}
function edit5() { retval=5;}
function edit6() { retval=6;}
```

Comment: Seems it will solve my problem, give me some time, i am just checking in live code